# In Matthew 26:29 could Christ be referring to the book of Enoch?

Tags: matthew, christology, 1-enoch, apocrypha

KJV Matthew 26 : 29

> But I say unto you, I will not drink henceforth of this ***fruit of the vine***, until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father's kingdom.

Christ promises that he will never drink the fruit of vine until he drinks it afresh in the kingdom of God(Paradise) and in the apocryphal book of Enoch  in chapter 8 he also describes two springs which bring forth oil and wine there in Paradise

> And in the midst of the trees that of life, in that place whereon the Lord rests, when he goes up into paradise; and this tree is of ineffable goodness and fragrance, and adorned more than every existing thing; and on all sides it is in form gold-looking and vermilion and fire-like and covers all, and it has produce from all fruits 4 Its root is in the garden at the earth's end 5 And paradise is between corruptibility and incorruptibility 6 And two springs come out which send forth honey and milk, and their springs send forth ***oil and wine***, and they separate into four parts, and go round with quiet course, and go down into the PARADISE OF EDEN, between corruptibility and in corruptibility.

Could Christ be referring to this book?

Comment: I suggest the question requires more research (more detail and clarity) to give credence to its stated opinion. The mere mention of a word is insufficient to give hermeneutic weight to an idea, I would say.

Comment: Which book of Enoch are you referring to?  It is presumably not 1 Enoch but 2 Enoch (and not 3 Enoch).  If it is 2 Enoch, then it is unlikely that Jesus even knew about it because it did not exist in Jesus' day!!  It was likely written about 50 years after Jesus died.

Answer (score 4):

There are three ancient books known as "Enoch" distinguished as 1 Enoch, 2 Enoch, 3 Enoch.  These documents are as follows:

- **1 Enoch**, "Ethiopic Enoch" - from about 2nd century BC and originally written in either Hebrew, Aramaic or a mixture of both.  It now exists largely in the sacred Ge'ez language.  This document appears to be quoted a number of times in the NT.
- **2 Enoch**, "Slavonic Enoch" - from the second half of the first century AD (at earliest) with copious additions probably until the early middle ages and originally composed in Greek but now only exists in old Slavonic
- **3 Enoch**, "Hebrew Enoch" - from the 6th century AD or at least the 10th century and is in Hebrew.

See James H Charlesworth, The Old Testament Pseudepigrapha" (Pub: Henrickson, 1983) for far more information, details, and translations.

The OP's quotation is from 2 Enoch and thus could not be known to Jesus and is unlikely to have been known to any of the NT writers.  Further, this document of 2 Enoch regularly quotes from the NT and appears to have been written or revised, or extensively added to, by a Christian writer some centuries after Jesus.

In 2 Enoch 8:6, the writer is more likely alluding to the book of Revelation.

Comment: + 1 I was apparently mistaken in thinking the quote was from 1 Enoch.

Answer (score 1):

The context of the OP's quote is the Last Supper, a Passover meal that foreshadows the meal Jesus will host in the Kingdom of Heaven. While a reference to the Book of Enoch cannot be entirely dismissed, it is more likely that Jesus referred to a better known work, namely the Book of Isaiah:

> On this mountain the Lord of hosts will make for all peoples
> a feast of rich food, a feast of well-aged wines,
> of rich food filled with marrow, of well-aged wines strained clear. 7 And he will destroy on this mountain
> the shroud that is cast over all peoples,
> the covering that is spread over all nations; 8     he will swallow up death forever. (ch. 25)

There are several other OT references to what is known as the [messianic feast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavenly_banquet), and it is also a feature of the Qumran Community's tradition as evidenced in the Dead Sea Scrolls:

> And [when] they shall gather for the common [tab]le, to eat and [to
> drink] new wine... the Messiah of Israel shall extend his hand over
> the bread, [and] all the congregation of the Community [shall utter a]
> blessing, [each man in the order] of his dignity. (1QSa 2)

That Jesus knew the prophecy of Isaiah is almost certain since he quoted elsewhere from him and read the scroll of Isaiah publicly in Luke 4:17. We can presume that he knew Enoch from its relative popularity at the time, as shown for example in its being used in the Letter of Jude (1:14). It is certainly also possible that he would have known the Essene traditions regarding the messianic feast.

**Of the three possibilities mentioned above, Enoch presents the least clear parallel to Mt. 26:29 because it does not mention the wine to be consumed at the great banquet while the others do. Since there is biblical evidence that Jesus knew Book of Isaiah fairly well, it is the best candidate for what Jesus refers to in Mt. 26:29**

Comment: There is also the difficulty that 2 Enoch was written AFTER Jesus died and rose.  It is more likely that 2 Enoch is alluding to the Bible rather than the other way around.

Comment: I see that now, and thanks for pointing it out. I upvoted your answer.